# Can a workflow with many, many subdags be performant?

Tags: airflow

I have a workflow that involves many instances of the SubDagOperator, with the tasks generated in a loop.  The pattern is illustrated by the following toy dag file:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator

dag = DAG(
    'subdaggy-2',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2017,1,1)
)

def make_sub_dag(parent_dag, N):
    dag = DAG(
        '%s.task_%d' % (parent_dag.dag_id, N),
        schedule_interval=parent_dag.schedule_interval,
        start_date=parent_dag.start_date
        )
    DummyOperator(task_id='task1', dag=dag) >> DummyOperator(task_id='task2', dag=dag)
    return dag

downstream_task = DummyOperator(task_id='downstream', dag=dag)
for N in range(20):
    SubDagOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='task_%d' % N,
        subdag=make_sub_dag(dag, N)
        ) >> downstream_task
```

I find this to be a convenient way to organize tasks, particularly since it helps keep the top-level DAG uncluttered, especially if the subdag itself contains more tasks (i.e. tens, not just a couple.)

The problem is, this approach doesn't scale very well as the number of subdags (20 in the example) increases.  I find that when the total number of DAG objects created in an overall workflow surpasses about 200 (which can easily happen with a production workflow, especially if that pattern occurs several times) things grind to a halt.

So the question: is there a way to organize tasks this way (many similar subdags) that scales to hundreds or thousands of subdags?  Some profiling suggests that the process spends a lot of time in the DAG object constructor.  Perhaps there is a way to avoid instantiating a new DAG object for each of the SubDagOperators?

Comment: We did some scaling test of subdag tasks (100/1000/10000) and saw that it quickly broke down by the way the Airflow scheduler is designed. I would recommend using vanilla `rabbitmq`/`celery`/… queue tasks when going past a few dozens of tasks.

Comment: Yeah, maybe this wasn't the use case that airflow had in mind? But then again it seems to me that supporting distributed processing over a cluster (i.e. the CeleryExecutor) goes hand in hand with supporting large numbers of tasks.

Comment: yup, I agree that's what we thought at first too. what we found was that the heartbeating process when the dags are iterated over timed out when you had a large number of tasks. maybe you can implement some `CeleryOperator` which basically just emits a large number of tasks (we tried this, but eventually ended up rolling our own DAG-scheduling tool to support this particular use case…)

Comment: I've got a DAG with 300+ SubDagOperators and 1000~ tasks total. I've also seen scheduling slow down / jam up sometimes, but things do eventually get through. The graph/tree views in the UI definitely load significantly slower and aren't always usable.

Comment: I've definitely noticed that the impact is greatest in the web UI (compared to, say, simply parsing the file with "python some-dag.py".)  It's good to know that the big dags can eventually run, but it's still unfortunate because the web UI is otherwise one of airflow's most attractive features.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that at least a significant part of this problem is indeed due to the cost of the DAG constructor, which in turn is in large part due to the cost of `inspect.stack()`.  I put up a simple [patch](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2610) to replace that with a cheaper method and there does indeed seem to be improvement - a flow with several thousand subdags which previously failed to load for me now loads.  We'll see if this goes anywhere.